# Postback with a timeout jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a postback using jQuery and ASPX, from the postback I need to get example:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#autost').trigger('click');
    }, 3e3);
</script>

<a id="autost" href="/downloadmusic/music.mp3">Download File</a>
```

Thats the post back result I get into the page, but the timeout won't set out, why? can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for my english, but the code posted above is the result from the postback.

Comment: Is there a syntax error at '3e3'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make an anchor click using jquery object. It will invoke the click handler bind to it. It wont redirect to the href if you use jquery trigger. You need to use dom object click to trigger anchor click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#autost').attr("download",true);
        $('#autost')[0].click();
    }, 3e3);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aJvUg/6/)

Comment: Why `$("#autost")[0].trigger('click');` not working but `$('#autost')[0].click()` working nice????

Comment: Its not getting triggered though... I have this:

Postback response:

<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#autostarttimer')[0].trigger('click');
}, 3e3);</script>

<a id="autostarttimer" href="/downloadmusic/music.mp3">Download File</a>

But it seems like the timeout doesn't start on its own?

Comment: @Manwal trigger("click") will fire the jquery handler attached to it. Thats why its not working. But $('#autost')[0].click(); will fire the dom click event. Which means it will redirect to the href attribute

Comment: @belthazorNv please see the edited answer. $('#autost')[0].click();

Comment: nothing still Anoop, its like its not getting trigger by anything :s

Comment: Its getting into the HTML of the website, but its not being triggered. :s

Comment: @belthazorNv see the edited answer. You need to give the download attribute to download the file

Comment: Hi Anoop, I have tried the attribute so I'm with:


`code`<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#autost').attr("download",true);
  $('#autost')[0].click();
}, 3e3);</script>`code`

But still nothing is getting triggered :s

Comment: Is there another way to do this? I have a page with ASPX (Ajax), and I need to start the download automatically for the file given. (Always in a postback..)

Answer (score 1):

Need to add something like below

```
$('#whateveryourid')[0].click()
```

[0] indicates the first element of the array - a selector returns 0 or more elements when its executed. 
hope it works for you